# Equation on Graph Issue: Computation failed in `stat_poly_eq()`: variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

Tags: r

I am trying to create a graph for my thesis data and am receiving the error message below. The graph runs, but the equations are not printed on it. I can't figure out what the issue is. There was a row with 'NA', but I removed it manually from the data.frame.

****Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_poly_eq()`:
variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')****

Any help will be greatly appreciated. The code for my graph that renders the error is below.

```
scatter.smooth(logspinbossht ~ logtestdia2)

df <- data.frame(logtestdia2, logspinbossht)

df6 <- df6[-c(574), ] ##remove NA

formula6 <- logspinbossht ~ logtestdia2
reg6 <- ggplot(df6, aes(x = logtestdia2, y = logspinbossht)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth() + 
  stat_poly_eq(
    aes(label = paste(stat(eq.label), stat(adj.rr.label), sep = "~~~~")),
    formula = formula6, 
    parse=TRUE
  )

reg6 + 
  ggtitle("Spine Boss Length vs Test Diameter") + 
  xlab("Log Transformed Test Diameter (mm)") + 
  ylab("Log Transformed Spine Boss Length (mm)")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your issue may be the consequence of object confusion.

Your code implies that you have two vector objects (named `logtestdia2` and `logspinbossht`) of
a particular length. These are put into the data.frame object `df6`, and one row of `df6` is 
removed.

Later you use the `df6` data.frame for the `ggplot()` call, *but also the formula that is based on the vector objects*. These vectors are one-element longer than the df6. The mismatch in length causes the warning.

If I'm right, your code might work if you **adjust the formula** as follows:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

# fake vector data
logtestdia2 <- log(sample(1:100, 1000, replace = TRUE))
logspinbossht <- log(sample(1:10, 1000, replace = TRUE))

# fake data.frame
df6 <- data.frame(logtestdia2,logspinbossht)

# remove row
df6 = df6[-c(574), ] 

# use the vectors from the data.frame
formula6 = df6$logspinbossht ~ df6$logtestdia2

# plot
reg6 <- ggplot(df6, aes(x = logtestdia2, y = logspinbossht))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth()+
  stat_poly_eq(aes(label=paste(stat(eq.label),stat(adj.rr.label),sep = "~~~~")),formula=formula6,parse=TRUE)+
  ggtitle("Spine Boss Length vs Test Diameter")+
  xlab("Log Transformed Test Diameter (mm)")+
  ylab("Log Transformed Spine Boss Length (mm)")

reg6
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed everything!